# SOAP UI - How to Capture REST raw Response in a file

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to capture the raw response for REST (POST) API call into a file using groovy Script.

I can see the response as below in *RAW*, but when file is produced it is blank.

REST Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-length: 0
Date: Tue 12 jul 2016 12:12:12gmt
WWW-Autheticate: OAuth
Server: Jetty (8.1.17V20150415)
```

I am using SOAP UI version 5.2.

Any help appreciated.

Groovy Script:

```
def Date startTime = new Date()
File it=new File("Result") 
def cur_Time = startTime.getMonth()+1 + "_" + startTime.getDate()
cur_Time = cur_Time + "_" + startTime.getHours() + startTime.getMinutes() +startTime.getSeconds()
def fileName = it.name + "_" + cur_Time
//Request File
def myXmlRequest="C:\\ConnectivityResults\\"+ "Rest_Request" + fileName+".xml"
def request=context.expand('${Testcasename#Request}')
def req = new File (myXmlRequest)
req.write(request,"UTF-8")

//Response File
def myXmlResponse="C:\\ConnectivityResults\\"+ "Rest_Response" + fileName+".xml"
def response=context.expand('${Testcasename#Response}')
def res = new File (myXmlResponse)
res.write(response,"UTF-8")
```

Comment: Why not just use `testrunner -A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't probably in your *Groovy* script, the problem is simply that your request is incorrect and nothing is returned as response. Based on the `http-headers` you show in the question:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
content-length: 0 
Date: Tue 12 jul 2016 12:12:12gmt 
WWW-Autheticate: OAuth 
Server: Jetty (8.1.17V20150415)
```

You're receiving an `401 Unauthorized` response instead of `200 OK`, and based on the `Content-lenght` which is 0. It's normal that your response is blank, so there is no content to save in file.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

If you want also to save the `http-headers` in a file, you can add the follow snippet to your *Groovy* script:

```
def fileName = ...
// http-headers file
def httpHeadersFilePath ="C:/ConnectivityResults/Rest_Request${fileName}.txt"
def ts = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('Testcasename')
def headers = ts.getTestRequest().response.responseHeaders
def httpHeaderFile = new File(httpHeadersFilePath)
httpHeaderFile.text = ''

headers.each { key, value ->
   httpHeaderFile.append("${key}:${value}\n",'UTF-8')
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks albciff. It is clear now, thanks for very detailed answer.

Comment: Is there any way to capture the response(as per above) and put it in a file?

Comment: @Geeme what did you mean? In case that response is blank, save for example the `http-headers`?

Comment: Hey albciff, Yes, whatever content appears in RAW, save that to file.
for ex :
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
content-length: 0 
Date: Tue 12 jul 2016 12:12:12gmt 
WWW-Autheticate: OAuth 
Server: Jetty (8.1.17V20150415)

Comment: @Geeme I update my answer explaining how to add the `http-headers` from the response to a file `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the late...

There's a simple way to take it and record in a file, using *Groovy Script* on your ***SoapUI***:

```
#Take the Raw Request into a variable "request":
def request = context.expand( '${Request 1#RawRequest}' )
#Take the Raw Response into a variable "response":
def response = context.expand( '${Request 1#Response}' )

#Create and fill a file "MyFile.json" whit the variables values:
new File( "C:/foo/bar/MyFile.json" ).write( request + response, "UTF-8" )
```

Hope that's useful.